# From NodeJS to C++ how shall I pass arguments and get the result

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I am trying to integrate my old C++ project with NodeJS. I have seen hello word addon tutorial to build simple file c++ file into NodeJS. I am looking for some advance examples, If someone has work on building bridge from NodeJS to C++. I want to pass data from my nodeJS  program (hello.js) to C++ program (hello.cc)

Thanks for help

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you show us what you have already tried and where your problem lies?

Comment: You can follow [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines to improve your question

Comment: Thanks  @Neuron I will post my code and use case where I am getting problems. I just got few interesting links in answers. I will go through it may be my problem is silly and it is already resolved  there in docs and I missed it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install `node-gyp` - you might have already installed 
`npm install -g node-gyp`

There is one very nice example please have a look 
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bengfarrell/4440739/raw/56e8291a31eb8f9714f8ca975c1e78a0788ae018/randomcoords.cpp

If you are not able to access please let me know I will past it here

to run this example 
As usual you need to build it 
and then create a binding.gyp file

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "randomcoords",
      "sources": [ "randomcoords.cc" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now in this c++ addon you can pass arguments like this

```
var randCoords = require("./libs/build/Release/randomcoords.node");
var cursor = randCoords.getRandomCoords3D(600, 400, 100); // params are max values for random output
console.log('{ "x":' + cursor.x +  ', "y":' + cursor.y + ', "z":' + cursor.z + '}');
```

There is a nice and short article 
http://www.benfarrell.com/2013/01/03/c-and-node-js-an-unholy-combination-but-oh-so-right/

Comment: Thanks for the article :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can find examples of using [NAN](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) to create native addons at:

- https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples
- https://github.com/nodejs/nan#example